# Scapy cannot sniff some packets

Tags: python, wireshark, scapy, packets, sniffing

I've tried using Scapy's sniff function to sniff some packets and compared it to Wiresharks output. Upon displaying Scapy's sniffed packets and Wireshark's sniffed packets on the same interface, I discover that Wireshark can sniff some packets that Scapy was apparently not able to sniff and display. Is there a reason why and if so how can I prevent it so Scapy does not 'drop' any packets and sniffs all the packets Wireshark can receive?

Answer (score 0):

Scapy itself has many libraries and extensions which are either pre-installed or you will have to install it based on your needs. Your question is a bit vague about what exactly is your comparison factor here between the two, but for example, Scapy will need a HTTPS decoder library installed for decoding the information of those packets. Also in Scapy, you can write your own protocol as you deem. But again if you are doing real-time parsing without a PCAP file Scapy is a good option even with the packet drop ratio. But if you are not concerned about the PCAP file I suggest to use Wireshark/TCPdump and record a PCAP file. You can dissect the  PCAP file using Scapy then. Hope this helps.